# ReentrantLock Fairness

Tags: java, reentrantlock

My ReentrantLock is not working as my expectiation. I expected the result of below code to have two threads locked and unlocked randomly but I got the result was always unlock on one thread. Can anyone explain ReentrantLock and I am trying to understand the fairness policy of it (i.e. new ReentrantLock(true)) and also tryLock() method. Thanks.

```
    final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true)
                try{
                    if (lock.tryLock(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                        lock.lock();
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " locked");
                        lock.unlock();
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " not locked");
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }).start();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true)
                try{
                    if (lock.tryLock(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                        lock.lock();
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " locked");
                        lock.unlock();
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " not locked");
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }).start();
```

Results in console:

```
Thread-0 locked
Thread-0 locked
Thread-1 not locked
Thread-0 locked
Thread-0 locked
Thread-1 not locked
Thread-0 locked
Thread-1 not locked
Thread-0 locked
Thread-0 locked
Thread-0 locked
Thread-1 not locked
Thread-0 locked
Thread-0 locked
Thread-1 not locked
Thread-0 locked
Thread-0 locked
Thread-1 not locked
Thread-0 locked
Thread-0 locked
Thread-1 not locked
Thread-0 locked
Thread-0 locked
Thread-1 not locked
Thread-0 locked
Thread-0 locked
Thread-1 not locked
Thread-0 locked
Thread-0 locked
Thread-1 not locked
Thread-0 locked
Thread-1 not locked
Thread-0 locked
Thread-0 locked
Thread-0 locked
Thread-1 not locked
Thread-0 locked
Thread-0 locked
Thread-1 not locked
Thread-0 locked
Thread-0 locked
Thread-1 not locked
Thread-0 locked
Thread-1 not locked
Thread-0 locked
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage is broken. You call `tryLock`, which may or may not lock (and the boolean it returns tells you what happened).

If `tryLock` worked, you **immediately call `lock()` a second time**, which is fine as it is a re-entrant lock, but you also now need to invoke `unlock()` twice which you aren't doing. **Every call to `lock()` and every `true`-returning call to `tryLock` MUST be accompanied by an `unlock()` call.**

Thus, whichever thread wins the race never releases the lock, ever, because you aren't matching your lock calls.

Given that you *must* unlock, there is really only one way to use locking:

```java
someLock.lock();
try {
  do stuff here
} finally {
  someLock.unlock();
}
```

and with `tryLock`:

```java
if (someLock.tryLock()) try {
  code goes here
} finally {
  someLock.unlock();
} else {
  code here if lock was not available
}
```

If your lock call isn't immediately followed by the keyword `try`, your code is broken. Note that the javadoc of the lock class mentions this and shows it in all relevant examples. [`ReentrantLock` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) - it's right there at the top.

Comment: Okay it goes well now with the correct lock usage.